# Display Web page inside a mono application

Tags: mono, browser

Is there a way to display a web page inside an application done with mono framework.  It is a cross platform application, so it would be great if the solution is in mono. It need not be a generic browser, i just need to display the web pages from my own server. The number of pages is too much also it will be updated often, so cannot include it in the app itself.

Any help would be really great. BTW the app will be for most of the mobile platforms, like android and iPhone.